# Use of character ';' in delete API path variable value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, path-variables

Path variable = "476%3B"

In a delete API, in path variable value, the character ';' is included in Id and is encoded as '%3B'
The id is passed as a string and later on in the app, it is parsed as an integer using Integer.parseInt("476%3B")
When this Id value goes thru the API gateway, somehow, the character ';' is getting stripped and using "476" instead of "476%3B" for Id. On execution of the app, I am expecting http code 400 (bad request) But I am getting 404 (not found)
The Id can only be integer.
Can someone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: You would possibly get 400 bad request if you use id as RequestParam instead of path variable. When you are using it as path variable, it becomes part of the API endpoint URL itself so calling the API with `;` will result as 404 NOT FOUND.

1 - URL endpoint with path variable = **http://localhost:8080/user/123**

2 - URL with request param = **http://localhost:8080/user**?123

Notice that in case 1, base URL will change if you append anything to the integer value (semi colon in your case) but in case 2, base url stays same and only the param value is changing

Comment: This ("476%3B") id value for the path variable is working fine in the local environment
It is not working correctly in dev and test environment where API gateway is used

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this UrlPathHelper::setRemoveSemicolonContent. By default it is true.

> Remove ";" (semicolon) content from the given request URI

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper.html#removeSemicolonContent(java.lang.String)

And you can configure it.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```